# C# XML find first Element descendants

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml, xelement

Looking to find `categoryId` and `categoryName` for first `item`.
It could also return no products.

XML Looks like this

```
<findItemsByKeywordsResponse xmlns="http://...">
   <ack>Success</ack>
   <version>1.13.0</version>
   <timestamp>2016-11-10T17:48:21.321Z</timestamp>
   <searchResult count="1">
      <item>
        <itemId>12354</itemId>
        <title>ABCD#</title>
        <globalId>ddd</globalId>
        <primaryCategory>
          <categoryId>**1234**</categoryId>
          <categoryName>**Catg Nameee**</categoryName>
        </primaryCategory>
      </item>
   </searchResult>
   <paginationOutput>
   </paginationOutput>
</findItemsByKeywordsResponse>
```

*Full xml [here](http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=TriState-d004-4e6c-adee-0fb69d721781&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&REST-PAYLOAD&keywords=065030860819&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=1)*

Comment: If there are multiple items, then I assume there is no attribute to distinguish them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your root element has a namespace defined what you should do when searching for the descendant items is specify the namespace:

```
XNamespace ns = @"http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services";
var result = XDocument.Load("data.xml")
          .Descendants(ns + "item")
          .FirstOrDefault()?.Element(ns + "primaryCategory");

var categoryId = result?.Element(ns + "categoryId")?.Value;
var categoryName = result?.Element(ns + "categoryName")?.Value;
```

*Also you can use C# 6.0 Null Propagation (`?:`) to retrieve the `<primaryCategory>` in a more elegant way. Keep in mind that if you do not have an `<item>` tag or a `<primaryCategory>` tag the result will be equal to `null`*

*In addition it might make more sense to try and find the first `<item>` that answers some predicate. If that is the case change the `.FirstOrDefault()` with:
`.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Element("itemId").Value == "12345")` for example*

Comment: @monsey11 - Tested on your given like to the real xml and works

Comment: Works, Thanks Gilad. תודה רבה

Comment: Did you mean `?.`?